# Converting an XML result (from XML query) to dataframe

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I am a complete beginner with R and cannot find a specific answer to my question so sorry if such a question has already been posted.

I am looking for a way to convert an XML result obtained directly from an XML query on R, and recognized as a "character" type of data.

Below is an extract of the kind of result I obtain :

XML result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<soft date="09/07/2018 12:11">
<name>
    <batch id="1">
        <p valeur="7"/>
        <lot id="754" esp="16" surf="15">
            <val1 valeur="710"/>
            <val2 valeur="260"/>
            <pval valeur="300"/>
            <res n="20">
                <year valeur="1998">
                    <y valeur="22.38"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="1999">
                    <y valeur="27.78"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2000">
                    <y valeur="29.75"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2001">
                    <y valeur="25.03"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2002">
                    <y valeur="30.07"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2003">
                    <y valeur="23.57"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2004">
                    <y valeur="19.47"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2005">
                    <y valeur="18.63"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2006">
                    <y valeur="26.73"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2007">
                    <y valeur="31.64"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2008">
                    <y valeur="27.11"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2009">
                    <y valeur="20.14"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2010">
                    <y valeur="27.87"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2011">
                    <y valeur="27.92"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2012">
                    <y valeur="23.05"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2013">
                    <y valeur="24.96"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2014">
                    <y valeur="29.86"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2015">
                    <y valeur="16.93"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2016">
                    <y valeur="24.52"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2017">
                    <y valeur="25.55"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
            </res>
        </lot>
        <lot id="755" esp="17" surf="15">
            <val1 valeur="600"/>
            <val2 valeur="530"/>
            <pval valeur="150"/>
            <res n="20">
                <year valeur="1998">
                    <y valeur="87.77"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="1999">
                    <y valeur="109.08"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2000">
                    <y valeur="109.23"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2001">
                    <y valeur="94.07"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2002">
                    <y valeur="97.64"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2003">
                    <y valeur="73.26"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2004">
                    <y valeur="86.13"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2005">
                    <y valeur="80.59"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2006">
                    <y valeur="66.57"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2007">
                    <y valeur="103.99"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2008">
                    <y valeur="109.23"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2009">
                    <y valeur="96.62"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2010">
                    <y valeur="85.96"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2011">
                    <y valeur="49.51"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2012">
                    <y valeur="107.55"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2013">
                    <y valeur="109.23"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2014">
                    <y valeur="91.19"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2015">
                    <y valeur="65.59"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2016">
                    <y valeur="109.12"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2017">
                    <y valeur="83.36"/>
                    <vol valeur="0"/>
                </year>
            </res>
        </lot>
        <lot id="756" esp="47" surf="20">
            <val1 valeur="600"/>
            <val2 valeur="600"/>
            <pval valeur="180"/>
            <res n="20">
                <year valeur="1998">
                    <y valeur="71.04"/>
                    <vol valeur="16200"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="1999">
                    <y valeur="89.07"/>
                    <vol valeur="12000"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2000">
                    <y valeur="83.88"/>
                    <vol valeur="16200"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2001">
                    <y valeur="75.76"/>
                    <vol valeur="13200"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2002">
                    <y valeur="87.29"/>
                    <vol valeur="14400"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2003">
                    <y valeur="63.4"/>
                    <vol valeur="14400"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2004">
                    <y valeur="63.77"/>
                    <vol valeur="12000"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2005">
                    <y valeur="52.18"/>
                    <vol valeur="16800"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2006">
                    <y valeur="78.48"/>
                    <vol valeur="9600"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2007">
                    <y valeur="88.58"/>
                    <vol valeur="13800"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2008">
                    <y valeur="83.42"/>
                    <vol valeur="16800"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2009">
                    <y valeur="63.8"/>
                    <vol valeur="16800"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2010">
                    <y valeur="76.76"/>
                    <vol valeur="16800"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2011">
                    <y valeur="84.86"/>
                    <vol valeur="13800"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2012">
                    <y valeur="64.59"/>
                    <vol valeur="16800"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2013">
                    <y valeur="67.49"/>
                    <vol valeur="16200"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2014">
                    <y valeur="88.59"/>
                    <vol valeur="12000"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2015">
                    <y valeur="51.52"/>
                    <vol valeur="12000"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2016">
                    <y valeur="65.2"/>
                    <vol valeur="16800"/>
                </year>
                <year valeur="2017">
                    <y valeur="74.5"/>
                    <vol valeur="14400"/>
                </year>
            </res>
        </lot>
    </batch>
</name>
```

I am looking for a simple way to convert this file into a dataframe on which I could run some basic statistics like boxplots, mean, sum, etc.

I did not store these results in any kind of file as I would like to run the whole process (query + results + basic statistics) directly on R.

Could you help me with this request ?

Thanks a lot,

Caroline

Comment: Are you sure this `xml` is valid? The `xml2` package cannot read it.

Comment: Hi Stéphane, thanks for your answer. 
I'm going to edit the post with a correct xml, it worked when I used the read_xml command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly want. Below is a code which provides `year`, `y` and `vol` for each lot in a dataframe. Do you need something else?

```
library(xml2)
xml_as_list <- as_list(read_xml("xml02.xml"))

f <- function(LL){
  inner <- function(i){
    data.frame(year = attr(LL[[i]], "valeur"),
               y = attr(LL[[i]][["y"]], "valeur"),
               vol = attr(LL[[i]][["vol"]], "valeur"))
  }
  do.call(rbind, lapply(1:attributes(LL)[["n"]], inner))
}

dat <- do.call(rbind, 
               lapply(xml_as_list$name$batch[2:4], 
                      function(L) cbind(id = attributes(L)[["id"]], f(L[["res"]])))
)
rownames(dat) <- NULL
```

This gives:

```
> dat
    id year      y   vol
1  754 1998  22.38     0
2  754 1999  27.78     0
3  754 2000  29.75     0
4  754 2001  25.03     0
5  754 2002  30.07     0
6  754 2003  23.57     0
7  754 2004  19.47     0
8  754 2005  18.63     0
9  754 2006  26.73     0
10 754 2007  31.64     0
11 754 2008  27.11     0
12 754 2009  20.14     0
13 754 2010  27.87     0
14 754 2011  27.92     0
15 754 2012  23.05     0
16 754 2013  24.96     0
17 754 2014  29.86     0
18 754 2015  16.93     0
19 754 2016  24.52     0
20 754 2017  25.55     0
21 755 1998  87.77     0
22 755 1999 109.08     0
23 755 2000 109.23     0
24 755 2001  94.07     0
25 755 2002  97.64     0
26 755 2003  73.26     0
27 755 2004  86.13     0
28 755 2005  80.59     0
29 755 2006  66.57     0
30 755 2007 103.99     0
31 755 2008 109.23     0
32 755 2009  96.62     0
33 755 2010  85.96     0
34 755 2011  49.51     0
35 755 2012 107.55     0
36 755 2013 109.23     0
37 755 2014  91.19     0
38 755 2015  65.59     0
39 755 2016 109.12     0
40 755 2017  83.36     0
41 756 1998  71.04 16200
42 756 1999  89.07 12000
43 756 2000  83.88 16200
44 756 2001  75.76 13200
45 756 2002  87.29 14400
46 756 2003   63.4 14400
47 756 2004  63.77 12000
48 756 2005  52.18 16800
49 756 2006  78.48  9600
50 756 2007  88.58 13800
51 756 2008  83.42 16800
52 756 2009   63.8 16800
53 756 2010  76.76 16800
54 756 2011  84.86 13800
55 756 2012  64.59 16800
56 756 2013  67.49 16200
57 756 2014  88.59 12000
58 756 2015  51.52 12000
59 756 2016   65.2 16800
60 756 2017   74.5 14400
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stéphane.
I tried copy and paste on my R consol, but the dat file is returning a NULL result. Do you know where it could come from?
I think this result should be fine enough as I should be able to perform some basic statistics based on this dataframe.

Comment: @CaroQ What do you mean by "the dat file" ? Do you have something in `xml_as_list` when you do `xml_as_list <- as_list(read_xml("yourfile.xml"))` ? I forgot to say that I deleted the two first rows of your xml example, otherwise there was an error.